# Can Visual Studio remember a MD5 of my source files in order to avoid rebuilding them when the timestamp changed but not the content?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build-process

Most of the time I am doing several distinct developments on the same project and, in order to have some logical separation between them, I use a personal version control system on a project (namely [fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org) but this is mabye too much detail).

This allows me to commit my work in different branches in order to merge them afterwards. Meanwhile I maintain a trunk branch in which I commit work by coworkers.

But when I switch from a branch to another one (in order to perform some merge action for instance) and go back to where I came from, Visual studio will detect timestamp modifications and rebuild files that have not really be modified.

Is there a way to ask Visual Studio to consider that a source file has changed when only some hash of its contents has changed?

**As the answer seems to be “no” here is another way of achieving what I would like, for which I am starting a bounty.** Still read the above please.

Do you know of a simple way to have a snapshot of the timestamps and MD5 hashes of my source files, and then, for every file of which the timestamp changed, compare MD5 and rollback timestamp modification if MD5 has not changed?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I suspect this would be better managed by getting fossil or your other source control tool to not change the timestamp if you file doesn't change. But it would be interesting to hack this into VS's build system too.

Comment: I agree with Rup. Switch to SVN, which I believe can be configured to not update the file last modified date if nothing has changed. And look into using MSBuild scripts so you don't have to do everything in the VisualStudio IDE. Very simple to use scripting language.

Comment: @MonkeyWrench: No. SVN requires installing a server. I will keep fossil because it is a single executable, needs no server or process running in background, and because it stores all my historical versions in a single file.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid this is not really possible.

The issue here is that this is not just a thing for VS but actually for the entire build system which is quite separate from the actual IDE.
In order to decide if and `.obj` should be compiled, VS compares its timestamp to that of the source file. Doing what you suggest will require the `.obj` file to include the MD5 of the file. This also goes for `.exe` and `.dll` files. Changing the binary format of these files and unlikely to happen for such a rarely needed feature.

---

Edit - I take it back, this is probably is possible in theory. One way to go is to write a VS plugin. The plugin would save the MD5s to some file in the output directory and the just before the build starts will update the modified dates of the appropriate files.

Thinking further, this might be possible using a pre-build step..?

Comment: You don't have to change the .obj format, though: you could compute the MD5 and store it (along with the last modification time of the .obj just-in-case) in an NTFS stream alongside the file. I don't think it would be necessary to do this for .exes and .dlls too - it's only the source-to-obj steam he's worried about. But I agree it's likely to be very difficult to wire up, and I wouldn't be surprised if the IDE checked this itself independently of the build system too.

Comment: Why put it in the `.obj` itself? This is overkill, alternatives are possible (create another file, an alternate data stream if on an NTFS drive, among other possibilities) (@Rup: same idea as you at the same minute)

Comment: I have updated my question. Maybe there is a system that would use `touch` or other timestamp modification software to revert non-significant timestamp modifications.

Comment: Also, if you do try to write an extension that does this, each text buffer has an interface for asking it for an MD5 hash (`IPersistFileCheckSum`), which is optimized to use a cached value if the buffer isn't changed, to reduce performance impact.  It's what is used by the debugger when it checks to see if the file version matches what was built.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround may be to write a script which looks at a file that Visual Studio isn't aware of and, if it has changed, copies it to overwrite the file that Visual Studio *is* aware of. The file Visual Studio sees is then excluded from source control, so it's timestamps shouldn't get touched.

The copying decision might be based on a hash, but it could just as easily compare the source and destination files directly.

Visual Studio definitely has the ability to include code generators in the build - which is what this script would be, in Visual Studios eyes. I don't know the details though - I get cmake to manage these things for me.

Comment: This could be a nice way of doing it. Thanks.